# Is it possible run Transmission daemon and Qt/GTK GUI at once in sync?

Tags: linux, gui, daemon, ubuntu-13.04, transmission

The title is the question.

Originally this Ubuntu machine was meant to be headless, but I installed LXDE. Usually Transmission is run by the default GTK+ GUI. Instead of making sure the daemon runs instead of the GUI I'd prefer to have the GUI and the daemon, but I don't know how, if even possible, to run both at once and they being in sync, of course.

We login as `jaervinen` when we use the computer, 1 login at a time, but I know that Transmission daemon has its own user, `debian-transmission`.

Comment: I don't know if Transmission supports using the GTK client as a front-end for the transmission-daemon, but [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) can do it; you can use its GTK version to connect to the daemon; its web interface has also more features than Transmission's one.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, I certainly hope this can be done with Transmission.

Comment: See also the question in [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197950/can-i-share-the-two-lists-of-downloads-with-transmission-and-transmission-daemon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am happily using [Transmission Remote GUI](http://code.google.com/p/transmisson-remote-gui/) for few years already. It is not exactly the Qt or GTK GUI but it works on multiple platforms very well. The package is contained in Ubuntu. Just install the `transgui` package. On the project site there are also current binary packages which run on Ubuntu.

Another option is to use [transmission-remote-gtk](http://code.google.com/p/transmission-remote-gtk/) which has a [PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~ajf/+archive/trg). Unfortunately I have no experience with this one.

Comment: Yeah, the former is the one we use too.

Comment: @Rautamiekka: ...but does it solve your problem? Now I see that I probably do not understand your question completely. Do you want to use a specific transmission GUI client or what is the goal you want to achieve? If you want to run the daemon + GUI architecture you must have the daemon running. Or do you want to use two instances of transmission on a single machine - the daemon and the transmission with integrated GUI (`transmission-gtk`)? If so what are the reasons?

Comment: The goal is to run Transmission GUI and the daemon simultaneously, in sync, so that the daemon keeps the program running when the GUI isn't, so we can use the GUI to see what's happening without having to manually ask the daemon with commands. We do use remote GUI to boss Transmission if/when we don't use the GUI on the very computer.

Comment: @Rautamiekka: If you want to connect from multiple machines (including the local one) to a single instance of a transmission client you should run it as a daemon. In such a case you can use the web interface or any suitable remote GUI client to control it (even from the local machine). The `trasmission-gtk` is not suited for this use (daemon and GUI architecture) and trying to synchronize multiple transmission clients with a single set of data is a useless complication.

Comment: I suppose I can try that, better than nothing.

Comment: We've moved to Transmission Remote GTK, offers more features, and indeed has PPA for Ubuntu since they offer just RPM officially. Chosen as answer, although not answered the way expected, but this way works about as well.

Comment: UPDATE, very last: Remote GTK may offer more, but you can't specify trackers in a bulk, which isn't good, so we're back to Remote GUI.